# Differentiability of fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x,\epsilon)\in \mathbb{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ be a continuously differentiable contraction: There is a k$\in (0,1)$ such that $$|f(x,\epsilon)-f(y,\epsilon)|\leq k|x-y|$$ for all x,y,$\epsilon$.

Show that the unique fixed point $g(\epsilon)$ which satisfies $g(\epsilon)=f(g(\epsilon),\epsilon)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $\epsilon$.

Could someone give me a hint on how to get started on this possibly? I am at a complete loss..

Comment: by contraction, $k$ has to less than $1$ strictly. Otherwise there may be no  fixed point

Comment: I guess, $k < 1$.

Comment: Apply the implicit function theorem to $f(x,y)-x$ and use that continuous differentiability is a local thing.

Comment: You are right about k. Sorry I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can apply the Implicit function theorem to $x-f(x,y)$. Or, you can argue as follows: Since $k<1$, it follows that $|f_x'|\leq k$.

First, we find that $|g(t+h)-g(t)\|=|f(g(t+h),t+h)-f(g(t),t)| 
\leq k|g(t+h)-g(t)|+M|h|$, where $M$ is upper bound for $|\partial_y f|$, which implies that $g$ is Lipschtiz. Then we have $|g(t+h)-g(t)|=O(\|h\|)$. 
On the other hand, since $f$ is differentiable at $(g(t),t)$, we know that 
$$
g(t+h)-g(t)=f(g(t+h, t+h)-f(g(t),t)=\partial f_x(g(t),t) (g(x+h)-g(h))+\partial_y f(g(t),t)h+o(|g(t+h)-g(t)|)+o(|h|), 
$$
which implies that 
$$
g(x+h)-g(t)=(1-\partial_x f_x(g(t),t))^{-1}\partial_y f(g(t),t)h+ o(|g(t+h)-g(t)|)+o(|h|)=(1-\partial_x f_x(g(t),t))^{-1}\partial_y f(g(t),t)h+o(|h|),
$$
because $g$ is Lipschitz. Hence we have that $g$ is differentiable and 
$g'(t)=(1-\partial_x f_x(g(t),t))^{-1}\partial_y f(g(t),t)$

Comment: A crystal clear proof.Amazing that we do not need to know how the fixed point is obtained, just that it is a fixed point.

Comment: @orangeskid Yes, even in the proof of implicit function theorem, the same idea remains. You only need to know that it is a fixed point.

Comment: Do you think that would also apply say for differential equations -- the smooth dependence of parameters and initial point. ?

Comment: @orangeskid Yes, a similar idea applies to differentiable function, where the proof is even simpler

Comment: I mean $y'(t) = f(t, \phi(t))$, $y(t_0) = y_0$... where you write an equivalent integral problem and look for fixed points